# Using JAXB to extract inner text of XML element

Tags: xml, jaxb, innertext

### Problem

Given the following XML configuration file:

```
<main>
  <name>JET</name>
  <maxInstances>5</maxInstances>
  <parameters>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>
      <b1>test1</b1>
      <b2>test2</b2>
    </b>
  </parameters>
</main>
```

I need to extract the value of the name and maxInstances elements and then the whole inner text of the parameters element. e.g.

```
name = "JET"
maxInstances = 5
parameters = "<a>1</a><b><b1>test1</b1><b2>test2</b2></b>"
```

Ultimately the parameters block can contain any well formed XML.

### Attempted Solution

The following code works for name and maxInstances but not parameters:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="main")
public class Main {

    @XmlElement(name="name", required="true")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="maxInstances", required="true")
    private Integer maxInstances;

    @XmlElement(name="parameters")
    private String parameters;

}
```

I've tried looking at solutions based on the following ideas but can't find something appropriate.

Is there a different type I can use for the parameters object representing the XML Tree that I could parse to produce a string? e.g.

```
@XmlElement(name="parameters")
private XmlNodeObject parametersNode;

public String getParameters() {
    // Collapse node to single line of text
    return innerText;
}
```

Or do I need to use some different kind of annotation?

```
@XmlSpecialAnnotation(...)
@XmlElement(name="parameters")
private String parameters;
```

Do I need to switch to a different style of parser?  Is it a good/bad idea to use two styles of parser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you could come is to map 'parameters' to a DOM tree, by declaring the variable to be `org.w3c.dom.Node`. (Actually, declaring a JAXBElement).

For details, see http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Avoid_strong_databinding.html. That gives you the schema-first prescription, you can see how to start from java by running that schema through xsd2java and looking at the output.

To get a string you'll have to serialize from the DOM.

Or, even more specifically:

[this page here describes xsd:any processing, and thus](http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/~raw,r=1.1.1.10/jaxb/www/guide/Mapping_of__xs_any___.html)

```
  @XmlAnyElement
  public List<Element> getParameters();
```

Where `Element` is the DOM interface.

Comment: Many thanks bmargulies, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Check out how you can leverage the DOMHandler aspect of @XmlAnyElement to handle non-DOM properties:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element/5553682#5553682

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation [as described by bmargulies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element/5537787#5537787).  To map to the object model in your question you can leverage a `DOMHandler`.

**Main**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="main")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Main {

    private String name;

    private Integer maxInstances;

    @XmlAnyElement(value=ParameterHandler.class)
    private String parameters;

}
```

**ParameterHandler**

```java
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.DomHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class ParameterHandler implements DomHandler<String, StreamResult> {

    private static final String PARAMETERS_START_TAG = "<parameters>";
    private static final String PARAMETERS_END_TAG = "</parameters>";
    private StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter(); 

    public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
    }

    public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
        String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
        int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(PARAMETERS_START_TAG) + PARAMETERS_START_TAG.length();
        int endIndex = xml.indexOf(PARAMETERS_END_TAG);
        return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }

    public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
        try {
            String xml = PARAMETERS_START_TAG + n.trim() + PARAMETERS_END_TAG;
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Main.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Main main = (Main) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(main, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, I came up with something very similar but your example is definitely an improvement of what I had.  Appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: I'm facing following exception when starting your code: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: Marshalling von Typ "java.lang.String" als Element ist nicht möglich, weil eine @XmlRootElement-Annotation fehlt]. But it seems to be a bug in jaxb.

Comment: Is there a way in xsd for defining
@XmlAnyElement(value=ParameterHandler.class) ?

Comment: If <parameters> in above xml file is a collection, a little modification to DomHandler will solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550197/domhandler-to-capture-text-for-multiple-records#answer-23570497