# Prevent JAXB to escape HTML markup within my element

Tags: jaxb

Say I have an object with a description field. This field could have a String value with some html markup.

```
"Say <b xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Hello</b> Wold"
```

When this Object is marshaled, I retrieve an XML with the following result

```
<description>Say &lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;/b&gt; World</description>
```

Instead I'd like the html markup to stay unescaped

```
<description>Say <b xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Hello</b> World</description>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with for instance an annotation on my field ?

Thanks for help

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JAXB to extract inner text of XML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper way how to prevent Marshaller to escape HTML special characters:

```
  marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.characterEscapeHandler", new CharacterEscapeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void escape(char[] ch, int start, int length, boolean isAttVal,
                               Writer out) throws IOException {
                out.write(ch, start, length);
            }
        });
```